# C# Memory Leak?

Tags: c#, regex, memory-leaks

The following code crashes after sometime due to high memory usage (I open taskmanager and its used memory keeps raising). But I cant see any memory leak except for garbage collection not doing its job. Any suggestions?

```
//Load a list of regex
//Load a list of phrases
//Open a output file

foreach (string regexString in regexList)
{
    int num = 0;

    Regex regex = new Regex(regexString, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    foreach (string phrase in phraseList)
            num += regex.Matches(phrase).Count;

    if (num > 0)
    {
        output.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", num, phrase));
        output.Flush();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Complete Code: http://pastebin.com/0SQYn44z

EDIT2:

I found and posted the solution (foreach loop)
Thanks for everyone that tried to help in anyway.

Comment: Is there any specific regular expression that causes the problem, or is it only when you have lots of them?

Comment: Why not just debug it and singlestep over it? Im guessing the foreach is taking a lot longer than you expected (maybe inefficient regexp, or lots of lookahead/lookbehind).

Comment: @DanielA.White It looks like a redirection to `Console`

Comment: the regexes are all in this format: \bsomeword1 someword2\b and I have about 300k of them and about 60k phrases

Comment: suggest you use a better tool than task manager to view memory, RedGate.com has the most popular. You mention the GC not doing its job, it doesn't work deterministically... there is not a way of knowing when it will kick off a collection. Actually to solve this porblem you need to capture the memory dump of the OOM and diagnose it with WinDbg.

Comment: What kind of stream does the StreamWriter write to?

Comment: Complete code: http://pastebin.com/0SQYn44z

Comment: Thanks for the code but to reproduce the issue I get an exception about data.xml - can we see this file?

Comment: The links to the data are dead already. Please add a sample of both datafiles to the question.

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell from your example, but it is possible that the `RegexOptions.Compiled` flag causes the problem. From msdn:

> Compiled specifies that the regular expression is compiled to an assembly. This yields faster execution but increases startup time. This value should not be assigned to the Options property when calling the CompileToAssembly method.

If a regex is compiled to an assembly, then the generated code can not be unloaded until you restart the application as .Net does not unload assemblies.

This means that if you have a lot of different regular expressions, and you don't reuse them, a compiled Regex is usualy not a good idea.

Comment: I tried without RegexOptions.Compiled and the problem persists

Comment: Okay, but stop using the `Compiled` option anyway.  The way you're using it, it can't possibly be doing enough good to offset its own cost.

Comment: I think Compiled is default nowadays.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I just looked at the source code of `Regex`, and it looks like `Compiled` is not used by default. This is in line with the msdn documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.90).aspx#Compiled

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that your regex uses excessive backtracking resulting in a long execute time and high memory usage

Can you post the regex and the input so I can check for sure?

Comment: The regex are all in this format: \bsomeword1 someword2\b and I have about 300k of them and about 60k phrases with avarege 500 characters length

Comment: OK, van you package up a small code sample and make it available for download? I've done a lot of C# regexes so can run and diagnose it

Comment: Your program is not self contained, I get: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad\data.xml'.

Comment: Ok I'm uploading data.xml wait a moment

Comment: night has fallen. Ill took a look tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

You use some types that implement IDisposable without calling Dipose():

- StreamReader
- StreamWriter
- XmlReader

Wrap the use of those types in using statements and see if that improves thing for you.

Comment: @HenkHolterman lines 33, 34 and 71 of the sample posted on pastebin.

Comment: Closing the Reader will close the Stream. But even leaving them all open can't explain the results the OP is getting.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your code, I can already recommend not using two, but one combined Regex. Something like:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(
        @"\b(?:" + s1 + " " + s2 + "|" + s2 + " " + s1 + @")\b",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Note that the series of `+` operators there is converted into a single `String.Concat(params string[])` call. With only 2 to 4 parts, it wouldn't even create the temporary array because there are more specialized `Concat` overloads for that case. `Join` always uses a temporary array and also needs to take care of the separator string, even if it's empty.

Another thing you might want to keep in mind is that running your program in debug mode will differ quite a lot from running it in release mode. For example that `keywords` list will remain live until the function returns. I recommend explicitly restricting its lifetime and also cleaning up the other objects as soon as possible. Maybe something like the following:

```
string[] keywordArray;
using (StreamReader keywordsFile = new StreamReader("keywords.txt"))
{
    List<string> keywords = new List<string>();
    string keyword;
    while ((keyword = keywordsFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        keywords.Add(keyword);

    keywordArray = keywords.ToArray();
}
```

Or skip it altogether:

```
string[] keywordArray = File.ReadAllLines("keywords.txt"); // internally uses above code
```

However, somehow I have the feeling loading your huge feeds file as a whole into memory is a bad idea. It would require a lot less memory if you could deserialize one `FeedItem` at a time and return it from an [iterator method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0%28VS.80%29.aspx). Then all you need to do is restructure the algorithm to have the loop over feed items as outer-most loop.

Comment: I found and posted the solution but really thanks for your advices on better practices, they were helpful at all

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I've got this right. You have a large list of keywords, and for every permutation of two of those words you create a new string by joining them together with a space in the middle, plus another string with the order of the words reversed (which is unnecessary, BTW).  Finally, you create a Regex object from each of the strings.

Having done that, you start iterating over your list of FeedItem objects, taking two attributes of each and forming them into a string like you did with the keywords, and try to match that string with each of the two regexes.  In short, I think you should hold off on the finger-pointing for the moment and concentrate on refactoring your code.  In fact, I advise you to forget about regexes for now.  You aren't using any of their power, and they're distracting you from your real problems.